# Mount Ext 4 Disk at boot

Tags: 14.04, automount, ext4

I followed this [guide](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Video-Frequently-Asked/UniFi-Video-How-to-add-an-External-Hard-Drive-to-the-UVC-NVR-or/ta-p/1294078) to get a 1TB Internal disk partitioned and mounted at boot.
I then reboot the PC and can see that the partition is created and and is mounted but doesn't show under 'Files'. If i type in `sudo mount` i can see this error: `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)`

So instead of following the guide to partition and mount the drive, I nuked the diskand then used GParted and the disks GUI.

If i then mounted the Partition manually by clicking on the 'Play'button the disks shows under Files.

Then i rebooted and it didn't auto mount.

I then manually set the automount at boot options from the disks GUI:

[image]

and rebooted but still never showed underneath files. I then used this command incase it was a permissions issue - `sudo chown administrator: /dev/sdb1`

rebooted and never worked.

I read on another forum that it was the "nosuid,nodev,nofail" options that were making it fail and that I should try replacing them with just "defaults". This hasn't worked either.

Comment: zanna - sorry i do have one more question if you dont mind? I didnt issue sudo mkdir /media/cctvstorage

but its appeared in the list when i issue sudo df

does this mean that when i entered it in the Mount Option GUI it was automatically created or is there no chance that would happen?

Comment: Oh yes, the GUI dialogue can create it in that case... I just edit `/etc/fstab` myself. I'll edit my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nautilus will list devices nicely if you put their mount points in `/media`, but not in `/mnt` You can call the mount point anything you like, for example `/media/my-drive` can be set as your mount point in the GUI dialog and this mount point will be created for the device you specify